# Wait for tmux session to exit abd execute command

Tags: bash, cron, tmux

I have gameserver running in a tmux session and I want to make a script that automatically restarts the server.

The scheduling can be done with `cron` from what I've read.

The script sends keys to the gameserver running in the session to save and exit.
But now I want the script to wait until the gameserver has exited (so until the tmux session has exited) and then proceed to start it again.

That's the part I don't know how to do.